# What's the full answer to "shall I"?

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

The form *Shall I* is used to make offers, in general. For example

> Shall I help you?

and one would answer

> Yeah, help me

but what's the full answer? I mean, with a question like

> You will go for meat, won't you?
>   *Short answer*: Yeah.
>   *Full answer*: Yes I will.

But *shall* as a second person has another meaning

> Shall I help you?
>   Yes you shall. <-- it's no more a suggestion: I'm requiring you to do that.

and using *Yes you will* still sounds imperative. Therefore, is there a full answer to that form as there is for normal verbs like do, will, be and so on?

Comment: Also consider, "What shall I do tonight?"

Comment: You could reply, "Yes, if you would."  to carry a modal verb forward.

Comment: This "full answer" that you're looking for isn't necessarily something real in English usage.

Comment: Just to underline this: "Yes please", or "No, thank you" are almost always best

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say, "Yes, please do."

In other words, if *will* in a question maps to *will* in what you are calling a "full answer", then *shall* in a question maps to *do* in the "full answer" – at least, that's one way we can look at it.

It's hard to say a mapping like this is 100% reliable, but it does seem to work in a variety of circumstances with a number of verbs. 
For example, consider these:

- Shall I help you?
- Shall I eat this last meatball?
- Shall I meet you at the market in two hours?
- Shall I just keep this book you let me borrow for another week?
- Shall I shut up and kiss you?

All of those questions can be answered with, "Yes, please do."

Of course, if you want to answer the other way, you could simply say, "No, please don't."

Comment: Are you thus stating that there is *no* full answer? My answer arose because it is, as you correctly say, generally answered that way and so I wondered if there were an actual full answer.

Comment: I don't think there's really a single, "full" answer to any of these questions.  Consider your question: _You will go for meat, won't you?_ You said the "full" answer is, "Yes, I will,", but there are plenty of other ways I could answer that question, like: "Yes, meat sounds delicious." "Yes, I'm starving!" "Yes, and I'll probably eat seconds, too." "Yes, but only a little bit – I want to leave room for dessert."

Comment: Yes but you're no more answering the original question. My point is that verbs like would and will can always be answered in a way that keeps such verb and I was wondering if that were possible with that form too. ("Will you go to the cinema? Will you help me?" can all be answered with "Yes I will"). Also consider "What shall I do tonight?", as  Damkerng T. points out.

Comment: I answered your original question as best I could. (I also upvoted it; it's an interesting question.) If the question is "Shall I [*insert verb here*] you?", the "fullest" answer I can think of is, "Yes, please do." So, if _will_ in a question maps to _will_ in the "full answer", then _shall_ in the question maps to _do_ in the "full answer" – at least, that's one way we can look at it.

Comment: The polite way to refuse a "Shall I ...?" offer would usually be "No, thank you" rather than "No, please don't" - the latter could be interpreted to mean that the offer was unwelcome!

Comment: @psmears - I think that's probably good advice 90% of the time or more. (I think maybe I was focused too much on my last question when I wrote that!) Nice clarification.

Comment: @J.R. No I was referring to the answers you gave("meat sounds delicious" etc.) to my first question. Anyway, can you add that mapping (actually the word I was looking for!) to your answer?

Comment: @black I agree with J.R. (both in his answer and all comments), "Shall I ...? " is best answered with "Yes, please do." (or "No, thank you."). The reason I posted my comment ("What shall I do tonight?") was because your question made me realize that *shall* is not quite like other auxiliary/modal verbs. We would normally use the same verb in our reply ("Do you ...?" "Yes, I do." "Can you ...?" "No, I can't." "Will you ...?" "Yes, I will."), and they seem to work similarly in *Wh*-questions ("What may he need to ...?" "He may ...") IMHO, the answers may or may not choose to address this matter.

Comment: (cont.) Personally, it seems to me that modal verbs keep evolving, and *shall* (and perhaps *will*, too) are a bit special in this respect, because their meanings seem to depend on whether the grammatical subject is the first person or not. A good (but controversial) example for showing the distinction is *I shall drown; no one will save me!* (as in I'm going to drown) vs. *I will drown; no one shall save me!* (as in I want to drown). (I found it on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would you write it up in an answer?

Comment: @black Thanks for the invitation! I choose not to write an answer because I don't have any better answer than J.R.'s, and I can't say that I know much enough about all the nuances of these modal verbs. (As a rule (for myself), I never post anything I just found on the web or just learned as an answer, because it would be too shaky and could be misleading for learners like you and me.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a valid and good question.

I look at the question in the following way...

Grammatically the right answer (FULL answer as well) would be:

> Yes, you shall.

But we normally don't answer like this, do we? (Technically the above answer is right.)

The reason is because the asker is not actually questioning his will or the event in the future, *but* he is *offering*/*suggesting* his future behaviour.

Similar example would be:

> Why don't we go to the gym?
>
> <s>Because we don't like it.</s> Sure, let's go!

So, the answer to the original question could be any of the followings and more:

> Shall I play tennis with you?
>
> Please do.
>
> Sure why not!
>
> Yes, please.
>
> ...

Comment: So you agree to say there isn't one in particular, unlike for normal verbs (like will, would, ...)?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @black - I'm not convinced there is "one in particular" for words like _will_ and _would_, either.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be: Is there a way to say the words "Yes, you shall" to convey a different meaning than the words "Yes, you shall"? The answer to that is no.

"Yes, you shall" is a perfectly valid way to answer the question. If you don't like the meaning that "you shall" conveys, then use a different word. There are infinite different ways to answer the question.

And for the comment from Damkerng T.:

> "What shall I do tonight?"
>
> "You shall dine with me."

If you say it with a smile, it sounds like an invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! (Informal answer)
Another way of saying it is Yes, you may. (or might)

Answer (score -1):

At times, we have to learn the language *as it is.* "Shall I help you?" can be answered in a various ways, three being the most common I can think of.

> Sure 
>  Why not? 
>  Okay *(less polite, IMO)*

However, I'd choose replying *(the full answer)*

> Yes, you *may*!

That's because the first person is *politely* 'asking' you to help and in return, you are giving ***the permission*** that takes 'may'.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Also see my comment below J.R's answer.

Comment: I wrote *the full answer*.

Comment: Damkerng T. mentioned "What shall I do tonight?" and you may does not answer that.

Comment: shall + I asks for the permission. And thus, my answer remains the same. 'What shall I do tonight?" ~ "You may better study."*

Comment: As for @Damkerng's comment, that's outside the scope of your original question, which begins: "The form _Shall I_ is used to make offers, in general." That's true, but the word has more uses than that: see [Macmillan's](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/shall) Defs 1a and 1b. I don't think you'll find a single answer that will aptly answer **every** question with the words "Shall I" in the question. Similarly, if the question was, "What will we do tonight?" we can't answer that with, "Yes, we will."